# How to seperate the lines in a FileReader file?

Tags: java, readfile

I am working with java. I want to work with a text file which is given to me by command line arguments. Now I need to count the lines in the file and work more closely with its content. How is that possible?

[image]

Comment: A simple web search leads to `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-`. Please do more research before asking.

Comment: Sorry, I am still very new to this forum and hadn't found that link before. Thank you anyways.

Comment: If you are quite new to java it might help you to go through the tutorials, e.g. [for basic IO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count lines in the file you must use `BufferedReader` or `Scanner` classes, they have `readLine()` method and all want you do is read line by line in cycle while line is not null and add them to `ArrayList<String>` in same time, after cycle done you have list with your text and his size is count of lines in the text.

Comment: If you accept the answer mark it as "accepted" according to site rules

Answer (score 0):

You can while you are parsing count the occurences of `\r\n`
this is called carriage return and linefeed sometimes both are used sometimes only one so look out for that